How do lengths function in tabularx environment
I was creating my table and I had some problems using the tabularx environment when defining the columnwidths. Look at this example
\documentclass[a4paper,
]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=2 cm,
    bottom = 2cm,
    left = 1.5cm,
    right = 1.5 cm
}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \the\linewidth
    
    \the\textwidth
        
    %   \begin{table}
        %       \centering
        
        \newlength{\anchoComun}
        \newlength{\nuevoAncho}
        \newlength{\anchoVertices}
        \newlength{\anchoprimeraCol}
        \newlength{\anchoColComb}
        \setlength{\anchoComun}{0.15\linewidth}
        \setlength{\anchoVertices}{0.35\linewidth}
        \setlength{\anchoprimeraCol}{0.2\linewidth}
        \setlength{\anchoColComb}{\dimexpr 3\anchoComun + \anchoVertices}
        \settowidth\rotheadsize{\bfseries\large Estación de muestreo 1}
        \noindent
        \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}
%           p{54.43623pt} 
            p{\anchoprimeraCol} 
            p{\anchoComun} 
            p{\anchoComun} 
            p{\anchoComun} 
            p{\anchoVertices}   @{}
            } 
            
            \cmidrule[1.1pt]{1-5}
             & \multicolumn{4}{p{\anchoColComb}}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{4 Cols}} \the\linewidth} \\ 
            
            \cmidrule[1.1pt]{2-5}
            \the\anchoprimeraCol& \textbf{Col 2} \the\anchoComun & \textbf{Col 3} \the\anchoComun  & \textbf{Col 4} \the\linewidth & \textbf{Col 5} \the\anchoVertices \\ 

           \cmidrule[1.1pt]{1-5}
        \end{xltabular}
        %   \end{table}
        
        \setlength{\anchoComun}{\dimexpr 0.15\linewidth}
        \setlength{\nuevoAncho}{0.35\linewidth}
        \noindent
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
        %           p{54.43623pt} 
        p{\anchoComun} @{} 
        @{} p{\anchoComun} @{} 
        @{} p{\anchoComun} @{} 
        @{} p{0.15\linewidth} @{} 
        @{} p{\nuevoAncho} 
        @{} |} 
        \hline
            \the\anchoComun & \the\anchoComun & \the\anchoComun & \the\anchoComun & \the\nuevoAncho\\
            \the\tabcolsep & \the\tabcolsep & \the\tabcolsep & \the\tabcolsep & \the\tabcolsep\\
        \end{tabularx}
        
        \the\anchoComun
        
        \newlength{\longtotal}
        \setlength{\longtotal}{492.5327pt}
        \noindent
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red] (0,1) -- (486.5327pt,1);
            \draw[red] (0,0) -- (492.5327pt,0);
            \draw (\longtotal,0) -- (\longtotal,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \noindent\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (486.5327pt,0);
        
        \noindent\tikz\draw (0,0) -- (492.5327pt,0);
    
\end{document}


As you can see, there are 5 columns and the first uses the multicolumn command. I've defined several lengths to be able to measure and print the measures. Note that the length of \linewidth is equal to 512.14963 pt and the first column has a length of 102.42836 pt, the next three columns have a width of 76.8193 pt and the last column has a width of 179.2555 pt. Fine, the width of the columns have been defined in this order:

0.2\linewidth
0.15\linewidth
0.15\linewidth
0.15\linewidth
0.35\linewidth

As you can see, the sum is 1 times \linewidth, but when compile the width of whole table is exceeded and I don't understand why
Please, if someone can explain me and fix this problem, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance :D
NOTE: I've add some lines with tikz to make a measure and be more sure about this.

A tabularx requires an X-column. Do you have one? No. Did you consider the gaps between the columns as part of your table width calculation? No.

Off-topic: top=2 cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5 cm may be expressed more succinctly as vmargin=2cm, hmargin=1.5cm.

as you have only p columns you should not be using tabularx at all and simply use longtable here.

You wrote,

As you can see, the sum [of the stated column widths] is 1\linewidth, but when [I] compile, the width of whole table [exceeds \linewidth,] and I don't understand why.

The sum you've computed is that of the usable column widths. However, the total width of a column is greater than its usable width. One must distinguish between the usable width and the total width of a column. The argument of a p-type column is its usable width, not its total width. The default total width of a p-type column is the sum of its usable width and 2\tabcolsep, as LaTeX by default inserts whitespace padding -- in the amount of \tabcolsep -- on either side of the usable material. In addition, if the table has vertical rules, one needs to add \arrayrulewidth for each vertical rule if the array package is loaded (which will be the case if, say, the tabularx package is loaded) in order to obtain the total width of the table.
A separate issue: In order to make tabularx and xltabular environments "work", at least one of the table columns must be of the X type. But in your sample code, neither the xltabular nor the tabularx table has any X-type columns.
LaTeX computes the width of the X columns as a residual, i.e., as the difference between the table's target width -- often, but not always, \linewidth -- and the natural widths of the non-X columns.
By default, all X-type columns have the same width. As the following example shows, though, it's entirely feasible to have X-type columns of differing widths. The thing to keep in mind is that the sum of the (relative) widths of the X-type columns must equal the number of X-type columns. In the following example, the tabularx enviroment has six X-type columns. The first five have a relative width of 0.9, and the final column has a relative width of 1.5; observe that 5*0.9 + 1.5 = 6 = number of X-type columns. Observe also that the usable width of the sixth column is 66.66% larger than that of the first five.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{vmargin=2cm,hmargin=1.5cm,showframe}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}

% Define a new column type that has a variable-width X column 
% and suppresses full justification:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{5}{L{0.9}} L{1.5} @{}}
    \toprule
    AAA AAA AA AAA AAA AA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE & 
    FFF FFF FFF FFF FFF FFF FFF \\
    \bottomrule    
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}

